# routing with non-restful actions issue rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have encountered a routing issue with rails. I'll explain as best as I can.

a user can use the create and index actions of the entries controller.

authenticated with devise, an admin can perform the rest of the restful actions on the entries controller. Furthermore, there are an additional three pages which I wish to add, 'pending, approved, rejected', so I added these to my entries controller like so:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_entries, only: [:index, :pending, :approved, :rejected]

  expose(:entry){@entry}
  expose(:entries){@entries}

    def create
    @entry = Photo.new(params_entry)
    if @entry.save
        record_saved
      return redirect_to(entries_path)
    else
        check_for_errors
      return render('new')
    end 
  end

  def index
  end

  def new
    @entry = Photo.new
  end


  def show
  end

  def pending 
  end

  def approved 
  end

  def rejected
  end

  private 

  def params_photo
    params.require(:photo).permit!
  end

  def get_photos
    @entries = Entry.all
  end

end
```

(note, this controller is incomplete, but for the purposes of my question it suffices)

I am trying to configure my routes so that the path to view these pages are like

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/entries/pending
```

so I have configured my routes like so:

```
  devise_for :admins  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  root 'home#index'
  resources :entries, :only => [:index, :new]

  namespace :admin do 
    resources :entries do
      collection do
        match :pending, :via => [:get, :post]
        match :rejected, :via => [:get, :post]
        match :approved, :via => [:get, :post]
      end
    end
  end
```

except I am getting the error

```
uninitialized constant Admin::EntriesController
```

expect if i change 'admin' to plural 'admins' and configure my view path accordingly I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/admin/entries/pending"
```

why is this happening? Am i  making the correct use of 'namespace' and 'collection'. How do I fix this issue?

rake routes:

```
                   Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
        new_admin_session GET      /admins/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
            admin_session POST     /admins/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#create
    destroy_admin_session DELETE   /admins/sign_out(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy
           admin_password POST     /admins/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#create
       new_admin_password GET      /admins/password/new(.:format)    devise/passwords#new
      edit_admin_password GET      /admins/password/edit(.:format)   devise/passwords#edit
                          PATCH    /admins/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
                          PUT      /admins/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
cancel_admin_registration GET      /admins/cancel(.:format)          devise/registrations#cancel
       admin_registration POST     /admins(.:format)                 devise/registrations#create
   new_admin_registration GET      /admins/sign_up(.:format)         devise/registrations#new
  edit_admin_registration GET      /admins/edit(.:format)            devise/registrations#edit
                          PATCH    /admins(.:format)                 devise/registrations#update
                          PUT      /admins(.:format)                 devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE   /admins(.:format)                 devise/registrations#destroy
                     root GET      /                                 home#index
                  entries GET      /entries(.:format)                entries#index
                new_entry GET      /entries/new(.:format)            entries#new
    pending_admin_entries GET|POST /admin/entries/pending(.:format)  admin/entries#pending
   rejected_admin_entries GET|POST /admin/entries/rejected(.:format) admin/entries#rejected
   approved_admin_entries GET|POST /admin/entries/approved(.:format) admin/entries#approved
            admin_entries GET      /admin/entries(.:format)          admin/entries#index
                          POST     /admin/entries(.:format)          admin/entries#create
          new_admin_entry GET      /admin/entries/new(.:format)      admin/entries#new
         edit_admin_entry GET      /admin/entries/:id/edit(.:format) admin/entries#edit
              admin_entry GET      /admin/entries/:id(.:format)      admin/entries#show
                          PATCH    /admin/entries/:id(.:format)      admin/entries#update
                          PUT      /admin/entries/:id(.:format)      admin/entries#update
                          DELETE   /admin/entries/:id(.:format)      admin/entries#destroy
```

FOLDER STRUCTURE

```
controllers > admin_controller.rb 
              admin > entries_controller.rb (this is the one with pending etc)
              entries_controller.rb (this is the public one with index etc)

views > admins >  index.html.erb 
                  entries > pending.html.erb, rejected.html.erb etc
```

Thanks

Comment: If your `controller file` is under `admin` folder then your controller class should be `Admin::EntriesController`

Comment: can you help me out a bit more, i added class Admin::EntriesController < ApplicationController
but it still says no route.

Comment: I'm confused with your routes.Can you post your `rake routes` output?

Comment: @Pavan, added routes and folder structure

Comment: Is your `entries` folder in the `views` which is having `pending.html.erb` is in `admins` folder?

Comment: admins folder has index.html.erb and the entry folder inside it. the entries folder contains rejected, approved pending.html.erb

Comment: That's ok.Can you tell me on which line did the error raised?